# Jquery - Show Tooltip IF Span is Empty

Tags: jquery, if-statement, tooltip

I'm trying to only show #tooltip when the span #attr-val is empty. But my IF statement doesn't seem to be working, the tooltip is always showing whether the span is empty or not... any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($("#attr-val").is(":empty")) { 
        $("#addtobag > input").hide( );
        $("#addtobag").hover(function(e){                                             
            this.t = this.title;
            this.title = "";
            $("#addtobag").css("cursor","pointer");                               
            $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>Please Select A Size</p>");
            $("#tooltip")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - 10) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + 20) + "px")
                .show();        
        },
        function(){     
            $("#tooltip").remove();
        }); 
        $("#addtobag").mousemove(function(e){
            $("#tooltip")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - 10) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + 20) + "px");
        }); 
    }
});
```

Example HTML is below:

```
<div>
<div class="options">
    <span class="prompt">
    Size: <span id="attr-val"></span><br />
    </span>

    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="Product_Attributes[1]:value" value="6" /> <a class="radio-select" href="#">6</a></span>
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="Product_Attributes[1]:value" value="6.5" />   <a class="radio-select" href="#">6.5</a></span>
        <p class="soldout" title="Sold Out">7</p>
    <br class="clear" />
</div>

<span id="addtobag"><input type="image" src="/images/2011/btn_addtobag.gif" alt="" /></span>
```

Comment: What's your HTML? The `<span>` could be full, after all.

Comment: Okay I added the html it looks like I might not be formatting the if statement in the right way - it needs to check whether that #attr-val span changes and whether it's empty or not, but I don't know how to write that logic out in jquery...

Comment: Insert this into your code: alert($("#attr-val").text().length);  What does it tell you?  as suggested by @Blender

Comment: I think you should trigger a function , whenever there is a change in span. In that you can check for the content using :isempty.